# Add Marker inside jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

i have trouble making a function that will add Marker to my leaflet map after it is instantiated.

My map.js is like this

```
function ($) {

$.fn.eqpMap = function (options) {
    var mapContainer = this;

    $.fn.map.container = this;

    $.fn.map.defaults = {
        adr1: null,
        adr2: null,
        adr3: null,
        cp: null,
        ville: null,
        geocodeAPI: "gouv",
        coordinates: {
            lat: null,
            lon: null
        },
        pays: "France",
        zoom: 15,
        osm: {
            layer: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            options: {
                fullscreenControl: true
            }
        },
        google: {
            options: {
                googleKey: null,
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false
            }
        }
    };


    var opts = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.map.defaults, options);

    function displayMap(location) { //location {lat: 1, lon: 1}
            //Récupère l'attribut id de l'element
            let idContainer = $(mapContainer).attr('id');
            opts.osm.options.center = location;
            if (typeof L.Control.Fullscreen == 'undefined') {
                delete opts.osm.options.fullscreenControl;
            }
            var map = L.map(idContainer, opts.osm.options)
            L.tileLayer(opts.osm.layer, {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);
            map.attributionControl.setPrefix(false);
            var marker = new L.marker(opts.osm.options.center, {});
            map.addLayer(marker);
        }
    }

    return this;
};

$.fn.eqpMap.addMarker = function ( marker ) {
    mapContainer = $.fn.map.container[0];
    // var map = window.maps.leafletList[0].map.getCenter();
    console.log(window.mapContainer);
    // var marker = new L.marker({lat: 1 , lon: 1}, {});
    // this.map.addLayer(marker);
}

 }(jQuery));
```

but everytime i try to add a marker in my addMarker method it just wont because it can't find the leaflet object or something.

Someone know how to help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a gloabl variable for the map `$.fn.map.map = null` and init them in `displayMap()` `$.fn.map.map = map`.

Then you get the map variable to add a marker:

```
$.fn.eqpMap.addMarker = function ( marker ) {
    var marker = new L.marker({lat: 1 , lon: 1}, {});
    $.fn.map.map.addLayer(marker);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i don't know why but i already tested it without setting it as null first. Didn't knew it was necessary.

Comment: can you pls check the answer

Comment: How can i make it wait until the map is loaded ? Because i have an ajax geocoding and the function that display the map wait for the geocoding data.

Comment: start the ajax call function in the `displayMap()` function

Comment: This is a bit more complicated, in fact the display map doesn't need an ajax call is some case, when the coordinates is sent to the plugin there's no ajax call and the function work well, i separated the ajaxcall from the displayMap() function because they are a lot of condition to tell wich ajax is called.

Comment: I solved it on my own ^^i just added a 
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    $.fn.map.map.addLayer(markers);
})